# Does the Infiltrator's time dilation effect apply to all Scoped Weapons, or only Sniper Rifles?

Tags: mass-effect-3

So, with the return of weapon mods, I'm able to buy scopes to improve the long range performance of my small arms like Pistols and SMGs.

Better yet, there are some awfully cool unique Pistols out there, like the [Scorpion](http://masseffect.wikia.com/wiki/Scorpion) which offers some unique utility if you don't need a Pistol as a primary weapon. Aiming the Scorpion with a Scope is devastating against, for instance, Harvesters, or clumped groups of Cerberus troopers as they're preparing to leave a dropship.

But I'm curious, as I've only had the chance to use this on a Vanguard: Infiltrators gain a time dilation bonus while looking down the scope of an SMG or Pistol? Or is it restricted to Sniper Rifles?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Infiltrator's time dilation bonus only applies when looking down the scope of a sniper rifle.

As a side note, I found the recoil on most SMGs prohibitive to scope use anyway, but your mileage may vary.

Also, though the other scoped weapons aren't impacted by time dilation, you can get enemies to stay in your cross hairs a bit longer by blasting them with Incinerate with extended burning first, then take your shots while they're standing there alight.

Comment: Yeah, I'm less interested in the implications for SMG's anyway. Now *pistols*, with unique options like the Scorpion and Arc Pistol, could've been interesting.